# how to save only value in pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-databricks

I'm saving value of a column from pyspark dataframe to a variable
that dataframe contains only one column
for ex:

```
variable=df.select(df['columnA']).collect()
print(variable)
```

output:

```
[Row(columnA='value')]
```

but I want variable to contain only "value"
how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(file_name)

variable_name = df[column_name]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Retrieving data from the "columnA" column
  for col in df.collect():
    print(col["columnA"])


# first row - first column
print(df.collect()[0][0])
```